# MOXy as XML JAXB provider in Jersey 2

Tags: java, eclipselink, jersey-2.0, moxy

I've added `jersey-media-moxy` to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${JERSEY_VER}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I have added `MoxyXmlFeature` to Jersey classnames, and I have a `jaxb.properties` file with `javax.xml.bind.context.factory` pointing to eclipselink implementation, but still I can't get MOXy to work as the Jersey JAXB.

The error I get is :

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml
```

And indeed, MOXy seems to have a MessageBodyWriter for JSON, but not for XML.

How can I manage to get it working ? 
I also tried to make my own MessageBodyWriter but it seems to ignore it.

Here is my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.xml.MoxyXmlFeature;
            com.test.handlers.MOXyXmlProvider;
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
            com.test.handlers.GeneralExceptionMapper</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logRestRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: It is probably the most common exception. Add `jaxb-api` as dependency. And make sure you write all the getters/setters for the fields and no-arg constructor for the model class.

Comment: I already have `jaxb-api` as a dependency. Actually, the problem comes from somewhere else because GlassFish JAXB impl work, it's only MOXy that doesn't.

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`

Comment: It is very long, I have a lot of dependencies

Comment: Actually It seems that MOXy doesn't provide any implementation of MessageBodyWriter for XML https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397125